# error by giving the go command install-unexpected directory layout

Tags: windows, go, visual-studio-code

Hey I'm new to go (golang) I'm trying to start an application but without success, he returns the following error when you give the command go install:
unexpected directory layout:

```
import path: github.com/gorilla/handlers
root: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src
dir: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api\vendor\github.com\gorilla\handlers
expand root: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src
expand dir: D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api\vendor\github.com\gorilla\handlers
separator: \
```

my version:

```
go1.10 windows/amd64

GOPATH "D:\BitBucketERN\GO"
GOROOT "D:\GO\"
```

my import in app.go:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "bitbucket.org/ernetworkdev/ern-admin-cadastro-api/handler"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/rs/cors"
    // Add the handlers package dependency
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
)
```

Full path:

```
D:\BitBucketERN\GO\src\bitbucket.com\ernetworkdev\ern-admin-cadastro-api
```

Comment: Please show the source with the import that causes this, and it's location in GOPATH.

Comment: I edited the question with the requested information

Comment: Hmm, still not seeing the issue. Do you have any symlinks involved in the paths here?

Comment: "github.com/gorilla/mux"
"github.com/rs/cors"
"github.com/gorilla/handlers" These are public

Comment: Are you importing two packages named handlers? Try renaming one of them.

Comment: Nvm, one is plural.

Comment: @GabrielSouza: I don't understand your response about the symlinks. The `go` tool doesn't follow symlinks -- are those packages actually located in the expected paths?

Comment: @Peter Sorry, I'm not good with English. I noticed that the folder structure was wrong the name bitbucket.com and bitbucket.org's thank you very much for the help, can you answer this for me to give you the points... Gracias